# android transforming eclipselink 2.6.4 hangs forever

Tags: android, gradle, eclipselink, dex

android build APK:

transforming eclipselink 2.6.4 hangs forever.

It works for 2.5.1. What could be wrong? The bytecode of version 2.6.4 is not supported?

UPDATE

```
apk group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'eclipselink', version: '2.6.4'
```

The eclipseLink jar is added into apk. Then

```
gradle assembleDebug
```

It hangs for hours during transforming the jar into dex.

Comment: You haven't shown anything - what works and doesn't work specifically? Weaving?  How are you running it?

Comment: updated question. It is not weaving. weaving works fine. thanks.